# regex to match a single character that is anything but a space

Tags: regex

I need to match a single character that is anything but a space but I don't know how to do that with regex.

Answer (score 344):

The following should suffice:

```bash
[^ ]
```

If you want to expand that to anything but white-space (line breaks, tabs, spaces, hard spaces):

```bash
[^\s]
```

or

```bash
\S  # Note this is a CAPITAL 'S'!
```

Comment: anything but white space ^[^ ]*$

Answer (score 163):

- `\s` matches any white-space character
- `\S` matches any non-white-space character
- You can match a space character with just the space character;
- `[^ ]` matches anything but a space character.

Pick whichever is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I use either `[^[:space:]]` or `[^ ]` depending on the situation.