# Compiler says Java code is invalid

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String aurgs[]) {

        System.out.print("Which function would you like to vist? L for Lottery, R for Random Math");
        char lotto = 'l';
        char rdm = 'b';

        if (console.nextChar() = lotto) /**error is here*/ {
            lottery();
        }
    }
    public static void lottery (String aurgs[]) {
        String announ = "Your lottery numbers for today are: ";
        System.out.print(announ);
        int [] numbers = {15, 68, 25, 66};
        double lucky = 50.2;
        for (int i: numbers )
            System.out.print(i + "\n");

        String announ2 = "Your lucky number is: ";
        System.out.println(announ2 + lucky);
        }
}
```

When I compile it, BlueJ says:

*cannot find symbol - method nextChar()*

I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: You can't just make up methods and expect them to work. No, programming is an exercise in precision, and compilers are unforgiving. You'll want to learn to use the Java API and use it a **lot**.

Comment: It may be because you are using the assignment operator = instead of the comparison operator == in your if clause, but @Hovercraft is probably right.

Comment: Being a bit more specific: There is no `Scanner#nextChar()` method. (But there are a number of similar questions, which makes me thing some professor or class notes started with an incorrect assertion ..)

Comment: Use some IDEs such as Eclipse, they will tell you what methods available to you.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746185/why-doesnt-the-scanner-class-have-a-nextchar-method , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340543/how-could-i-extend-java-util-scanner-class-to-add-a-nextchar-method?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The `Scanner` class has no `nextChar()` method. The methods available are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), none of which are `nextChar()`. You can instead use `next()` and read a single character as a string.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand what is wrong.

It is simple. Scanner doesn't have `nextChar()` method.

If you want to read characters with Scanner you can change its delimiter to empty string `""`

```
console.useDelimiter("");
```

and use `next()` method.

---

Also you should add one more `=` in

```
if (console.nextChar() = lotto)
```

if you want to compare chars (single `=` is used for assigning values).

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a `char` from a `Scanner` you need to use `next()`, which returns a `String`.
Then just get the first `char` from that.

```
char x = console.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now. Thanks.

Comment: No worries -- happens to everybody