# I don't know how to work with arrays for an average letter program

Tags: java, arrays, ascii

I need to create a program using the getAverage method and the main method to have the user input five chars and then calculate/print the average ASCII value and the highest letter, but Eclipse is giving me a lot of errors and I am not really sure what I am doing

```
   public static int getAverage(char [] ascii, int [] decimal, int [] letters) {
{       

    System.out.println("Enter 5 letters from the English Alphabet: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

IM TRYING TO GET THE LETTER TO STORE AS AN ASCII NUMBER HERE

```
   System.out.println("Letter 1 (a-z or A-Z): ");
    char a = (input.next()).charAt(0);
        int letterOne = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++){
            if (ascii[i] == a)
                letterOne=i;
        }
    System.out.println("Letter 2 (a-z or A-Z): ");
    char b = (input.next()).charAt(0);
        int letterTwo = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++){
            if (ascii[i] == b)
                letterTwo=i;
        }
    System.out.println("Letter 3 (a-z or A-Z): ");
    char c = (input.next()).charAt(0);
        int letterThree = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++){
            if (ascii[i] == c)
                letterThree=i;
    }
    System.out.println("Letter 4 (a-z or A-Z): ");
    char d = (input.next()).charAt(0);
        int letterFour = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++){
            if (ascii[i] == d)
                letterFour=i;
    }
    System.out.println("Letter 5 (a-z or A-Z): ");
    char e = (input.next()).charAt(0);
        int letterFive = -1;
            for(int i=0; i<ascii.length; i++){
                if (ascii[i] == e)
                    letterFive=i;
    }
```

I DONT KNOW HOW TO MAKE THESE INTO AN ARRAY THAT I CAN USE IN THE MAIN

```
    int[] letter = new int{letterOne, letterTwo, letterThree, letterFour, letterFive}; 

    int [] lettersArray = {a, b, c, d, e};
    int average = ((a+b+c+d+e)/5);


    System.out.println("Your average value is: " + average);
```

NOT SURE WHAT TO RETURN HERE IF ANYTHING?

```
     return ;

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] decimalArray = new int[52];
    char[] asciiArray = new char[52];

    int base = 65;

    for (int i=0; i<26;i++){
        decimalArray[i] = base;
        asciiArray[i] = (char) base;
        base++;
    }
    base = 97;
    for(int i = 26; i<52; i++){
        decimalArray[i] = base;
        asciiArray[i] = (char) base;
        base++;
    }

    int [] lettersArray = new int[5];
```

NOT SURE HOW TO CHANGE FROM A CHAR TO AN INT HERE

```
    int[] letters = new int[5];
    char max = letters[0]
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                if(max < letters[i])
                    max = letters[i];
            }

    getAverage(asciiArray, decimalArray, lettersArray);

    System.out.println("The highest letter is: " + max);


}



}
```

Comment: Let's start with the syntax errors: (1) Do you have something at the top that says "public class SomeName {"?  (2) You have an extra `{` after the start of `getAverage`.  That will cause a lot of errors right away.  (3) `int letter[] = new int[] { letterOne, ...`.  You need square brackets after `int`.  Use the same syntax for `lettersArray`.  (4) `getAverage` was declared as returning an `int`, so you need to put some integer variable or expression after `return`.  (5) `char max = letters[0]` needs a `;`.  That won't fix all the problems but get you closer to compiling.

Answer (score 0):

1: Ascii value.

In Java, a `char` holds an ascii, aka: numeric, aka: integer, value, however, when you try to print it, the character represented by that value will be shown.

```
    char a = 97;
    System.out.println( a ); // output: a

    char avg = ('a' + 'c') / 2;
    System.out.println( avg ); // output: b

    int b = (int)avg;
    System.out.println( b ); // output: 98
```

2: I don't know how to make an array to use in main

The main method is `static`, this means it exists without an instance of the class being created first and may be invoked at any time. The array you've declared is not static and `main` may not refer to the array because the array doesn't exist until an instance of the class has been created. Make the array static (at your own peril), or use `main` to create a `new` instance of your class and then tell the instance what to do.

3: Not sure what to return here.

You said up in your method declaration that you would return an `int`, you damn well better, or Java will get angry.

4: Not sure how to cast a char to an int.

Review my code in the first part of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you require accessing the values the user entered previously, then you don't necessarily need an array. You could do it just like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ASCII_Average_Calculator {
  public static void main(String []args){
    int n_letters = 5;//the amount of letters you want to capture

    int sum = 0;
    int ascii = 0;//this will hold the ascii value
    double average = 0;

    String letters = new String();

    for (int i = 0; i < n_letters; ++i) {
      System.out.println("Letter " + (i+1) + " (a-z or A-Z):");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      char c = input.next().charAt(0);//see this link for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

      ascii = (int)c;//cast the character to an int

      //perform comparisons to see if it is not within the limits for
      //lowercase ascii values: (97 to 122)
      //uppercase ascii values: (65 to 90)
      //and ensure that the value captured is within those limits (i.e. valid for a-z and A-Z)
      while ((!(ascii > 96) && (ascii <= 96 + 26)) ||
          (!(ascii > 64) && (ascii <= 64 + 26))) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry: \"" + c + "\"! Please try again.");
        System.out.println("Letter " + (i+1) + " (a-z or A-Z):");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        c = input.next().charAt(0);
        ascii = (int)c;
      }

      sum += ascii;//increment the sum

      if (i == n_letters - 1) {
        letters += c;
      }
      else {
        letters += c + " , ";
      }
    }

    //finally, compute the average
    average = sum/(double)n_letters;

    System.out.println("The average of the letters: \"" + letters + "\" is " + average);
  }
}
```

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
Letter 1 (A-z or A-Z):
a
Letter 2 (A-z or A-Z):
v
Letter 3 (A-z or A-Z):
b
Letter 4 (A-z or A-Z):
x
Letter 5 (A-z or A-Z):
e
```

OUTPUT:

```
The average of the letters: "a , v , b , x , e" is 106.8
```

REFERENCES:

[Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

http://www.asciitable.com/