# how to declare inputs on one line in java

Tags: java, input

I'm having trouble making my program read in all of the integers on one line rather than having to enter each number and hit enter after each digit in the terminal window.

For example, the terminal window would read:

```
For the our text enter the first 9 digits: 013292373"
```

rather than

```
For the our text enter the first 9 digits: 0
1
2
3
... etc"
```

My code looks like this so far:

```
/**
* This program calculates the last number of a 10 digit ISBN number.
*/  
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ISBNnum
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   //Variables and Scanner
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int dOne;
   int dTwo;
   int dThree;
   int dFour;
   int dFive;
   int dSix;
   int dSeven;
   int dEight;
   int dNine;
   int checksum;

   //Input
   System.out.print("For the our text enter the first 9 digits: ");
   dOne = input.nextInt();
   dTwo = input.nextInt();
   dThree = input.nextInt();
   dFour = input.nextInt();
   dFive = input.nextInt();
   dSix = input.nextInt();
   dSeven = input.nextInt();
   dEight = input.nextInt();
   dNine = input.nextInt();

   //Calculation
   checksum = ((dOne * 1) + (dTwo * 2) + (dThree * 3) + (dFour * 4) + (dFive * 5) + (dSix * 6) +
   (dSeven * 7) + (dEight * 8) + (dNine * 9)) % 11;

   //Output
   if (checksum == 10)
   {
       System.out.print("The whole ISBN is "+dOne+dTwo+dThree+dFour+dFive+dSix+dSeven+dEight+
       dNine+"X");
    }
    else if (checksum < 10)
    {
    System.out.println("The whole ISBN is " + dOne + dTwo + dThree + dFour + dFive + dSix +
    dSeven + dEight + dNine + " - " + checksum);
}
}
}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*");
```

**Adapted from**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using a scanner and splitting the `String` into a `String[]` by the spaces

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)
        String input = s.nextLine();
        String[] parts = input.split(" ");
        for (String part : parts) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
}
```

I extended my above answer with the below code. It worked when I compiled and ran it, separating nine numbers by the spaces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variables and Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[9];
    int checksum = 0;

    //Input
    System.out.print("For the our text enter the first 9 digits, separated by spaces: ");
    String numInput = input.nextLine();
    String[] parts = numInput.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        checksum += numbers[i] * (i + 1);
    }
    //Calculation
    checksum %= 11;
}
```

Tracing through the code, first I create a `Scanner input` object, an `int[] numbers` with 9 indices, and an `int checksum` instantiated at zero. Next, I prompt the user to input nine numbers, separated by spaces, then receive the entire line with `input.nextLine()`, which returns the `stdin` up to a newline character. I then split the `numInput` into a `String[] parts` by the spaces, making everything up the first space index zero, second space is index one, etc.. I iterate through the list, changing each `String` representation of the numbers into `int` objects and place it in the `numbers` array at index `i`. I then update the `checksum` `Integer` with `numbers[i]` (the number just converted) and multiply by `i+1`. After the loop, I modulus the `checksum` by 11.

The input on the terminal will look like

`For the our text enter the first 9 digits, separated by spaces: 1 4 6 2 8 7 2 4 10`

If you wanted to, change the line where it says `String[] parts = input.split(" ");` to `String[] parts = input.split(",");` and you could input your numbers like so:

`1,4,6,2,8,7,2,4,10`

Comment: Being a newbie at this stuff i'm having trouble understanding what exactly i need to use where. I haven't learned what i need to enter in this block of code that would relate to mine. Would you mind providing some clarification as to what i need to do to manipulate these instructions to work for me