# why cant java find a symbol i have initialized?

Tags: java, symbols

according to the following:

```
triangles.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    shape = keyboard.nextChar();
                            ^
    symbol:   method nextChar()
    location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
1 error
```

why is it not finding symbol? i have keyboard initialized as the scanner. how would i fix this?

this is how i initialized it:

```
char shape;
shape = scanner.nextChar();
```

i have changed char to String, but that did nothing. i have imported a scanner, so thats not an issue.

Comment: What is `nextChar()`? Why would you think the error is on `shape`, when the error message says `cannot find symbol` and then tells you what symbol `symbol:   method nextChar()` and the `location`?

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't have a `nextChar()` method.

Comment: Your compilation error says `shape = keyboard.nextChar();`, but your code snippet says `shape = scanner.nextChar();`

Comment: I believe you may find your answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to find the char within a String variable, just do something like:

```
 String str = scanner.nextLine(); // or scanner.next();
 char shape = str.charAt(i); // replace i with index of char you're trying to find.
```

hope that helps