# How can I enter "char" using Scanner in java?

Tags: java

I have a question

**how can I enter `char` using Scanner in java?**

Such as for integer number

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int a = input.nextInt();
```

but how can I do the same for char?

thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the difference between a single char and String of length 1? There are hasNextByte() and nextByte();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

See that answer :)

Comment: both have the same result but it is not the nice style that you say to the user to enter the "char" but user can enter "string"

Answer (score 3):

You could take the first character from Scanner.next:

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

To consume exactly one character you could use:

```
char c = reader.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
```

To consume strictly one character you could use:

```
char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do [input.next(pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29) to get the next input which matches a certain pattern. If you set this to "." then it will just get the next character entered.

```
char c = input.next(".").charAt(0);
```

Comment: thanks but this is not for "char" this is for "String" because you can enter more than 1 "char" by this way but only accept the "index 0" of the "string". you can enter by this way "char c=input.nextLine().charAt(0);" but I don't want this way I want only enter "1 char"

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the `Scanner` to take in the single character as a `String`:

```
String s = input.next();
```

and then you could convert the String to a char like this:

```
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

then again, as @Elliott Frisch mentioned, you could just stop at the first line

Comment: If you wanted to do it that way why not just go straight to `s.charAt()`?

Comment: whoops. Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read chars use InputStreamReader

```
    Reader input=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    char c = (char)input.read();
```

Comment: class Reader in what package?

Comment: thanks I will tested but it is the same thing like this char c=input.nextLine().charAt(0); I want to let the user only 1 char not enter the string and accpet index 0 of the string.

Comment: the difference is that reading chars is what Reader is made for, while Scanner is not designed for reading chars though you can do it using some tricks like that one

Answer (score 0):

```
String char
println("Password: ")
char = input.nextLine()
println(char)
```

The above will print all the characters the user inputs.