# Make the scanner.nextInt() read a "q" as quit instead of reading it as a wrong input

Tags: java, string, integer

```
 int rollnumber;
 do {
     try {
         System.out.println("how many times");
         rollnumber = scanner.nextInt();

         nigh=2;

        if (Integer.toString(rollnumber).equals("q")  )   {
               System.exit(0);
         }   
     } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
        scanner.nextLine()';    
    }
}while (nigh==1);
```

Basically, I'm trying to make a "q" (quit) option but it just keeps jumping to the catch statement when I press q. Help me make it so that the "scanner.nextInt()" reads the q as the actual quit command.

Comment: You need to read from scanner.nextChar() check whether it's quit command and then if not convert it to int.

Comment: Nesting()accepts int so when you pass char then it will go to catch and its obvious

Comment: Please format your code when you asking questions.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner/13942707#13942707) may help :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to read an `int` from the console. If you enter `q`, `nextInt` attempts to convert `q` to an integer, fails with a `NumberFormatException` and the code jumps to the `catch` block.

You should read with `next` or `nextLine` and convert the input to an `int`.

Comment: There is no such method `nextChar` in `Scanner`

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: I made a:  String stringy=scanner.next();  rollnumber=Integer.parseInt(stringy);  and then tried to:  if (rollnumber.equals("q")  )   
          {System.exit(0);}  however, the error is int cannot be deferenced. Im not sure what that means and what im doing wrong still

Comment: You should check for 'q' BEFORE casting to int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way. Read `String` not `int`.You can use nextLine()

Then

```
rollnumber = scanner.nextLine(); // read next line
if("q".equalsIgnoreCase(rollnumber)) // if it is q then if condition matched
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .nextInt will only take in an actual int. You could use the .next() method instead of the .nextInt() method and then check to see if it is a "q". If it's not, you could then check if it parses to an Int and if not, use the code in the catch block.

```
String rollnumber;
try {
    System.out.println("how many times");
    rollnumber = scanner.next();

    nigh=2;

    if (rollnumber.equals("q")  )   {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(rollnumber);
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
    scanner.nextLine()';    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your line to

```
int rollnumber;
nigh = 1; // added
do {  
 try {       
     System.out.println("how many times");
     String response = scanner.nextLine(); // changed

     rollnumber = scanner.nextInt();     
     nigh=2;
    if(if("q".equalsIgnoreCase(response)){){  // changed
       System.exit(0);
     } else {
             rollnumber = scanner.nextInt();     
             nigh=2;
     }
  }
 catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
    scanner.nextLine();    
   }     
 }while (nigh==1);
```