# Cannot get char user input to work

Tags: java, eclipse

This is what I have in my code

```
  char guess = Keyboard.readChar();
```

but the error message comes up as "`The method readChar() is undefined for the type scanner`" The scanner i have is `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in)`. Why Is this wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this

```
 char guess = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) does not have a method to read a `char`. Fundamentally, `System.in` is a buffered stream. You can read a line,

```
while(keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = keyboard.nextLine();
  char[] chars = line.toCharArray(); // <-- the chars read.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using `nextLine()` which reads in a String of text.

```
char code = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

`charAt(0)` takes in the first character of the received input.

---

**Additional Note:**
If you want to convert user inputs to upper/lower case. This is especially useful.

You can chain String methods together:

```
char code1 = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);    //Convert input to uppercase
char code2 = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);    //Convert input to lowercase
char code3 = keyboard.nextLine().replace(" ", "").charAt(0); //Prevent reading whitespace
```