# Scanner - Only 1 Character

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

The code below is from: [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);

Why does this take in strictly one character?
Any references where I can read about the purpose of the "."?

Answer (score 1):

The character `.` reffers a Regular Expression (Regex) that means any character.

As you can find in the documentation of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> Predefined character classes
>
> .  Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

Regular Expression is a way to find, match text with some predefined Pattern. If you want to find the next `A` ou `B` letter, you should use:

```
char c = reader.next("[AB]").charAt(0);
```

Take a look at the Pattern documentation to learn better how to use this API.