# How do I split a String by Characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

I've tried numerous times with different regexes but none seem to work. Basically, I have a StringTokenizer that is currently splitting the string by spaces, but I want it to split by each character instead. My current code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

This gets a string's character at index zero. Strings begin at index zero. Also, an alternative is

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars; ++i){
    // get the character using charAt(i)
    // store the character using an array, as others have specified
}
```

Remember to use `new Scanner(BufferedReader(FileReader("test.txt")));`

For more info, read [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a StringTokenizer that is currently splitting the string by spaces,

Read the `StringTokenizer` API. If you don't specify the delimiters, then the default delimeters are used.

So you need to specify all the delimeters.

Or, and easier approach is to just use the `String.toCharArray()` method and iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you need them as chars:

```
char[] characters = br.readLine().toCharArray();
```

If you need them as Strings:

```
String[] characters = br.readLine().split("");
```