# Java input from console

Tags: java, input, console

I need to ask for coordinates, so I would only like to read a SINGLE character(from console). How is it done?
I can't find anything in the documentation/tutorials.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first search engine result led me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

char firstChar = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

for a String, and you can use *this* code for ints:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int firstNumber = in.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates are actually numbers (believe it or not) so you would need to read 2 int variables, x and y axis. (Eg. X23 Y37)

In order to do so u need to import Java.util.scanner at the beginning of your program.

```
Import Java.util.scanner
```

Wherever you want to ask for the coordinates do this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("input x: ");
int x = scan.nextInt();
```

You might wanna define x as a global variable for other part of your code to use it but that's all u really need.
Now just do the same as the y and u got ur coodinates