# How to extract a single character from a scanner in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

What all I want to do is extract a single character every time from a text file, no matter it is a whitespace and/or new line character, till the eof.
Would using ""(empty string) as a delimiter work?

```
scanner.next().charAt[0]
```

The above code will take the first character of the string returned by

```
scanner.next()
```

and ignore the rest of the part. But I want just a single character every time from a file without ignoring any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a char input from the Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to read a file character by character, use a Reader, not a Scanner. A Scanner is for "scanning" for specific patterns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on Reader? Suppose my file's contents are: I A.\n(new line). I want each of these characters separately as 'I' , ' '(space) , 'A' , '.' , '\n'(new line character)