# Java Scanner get char

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] exampleString;
        char expression;
        Scanner getExp = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(expression = getExp.next().charAt(0))
        {
           // myString will added by expression character
        }

    }
}
```

I tried it on Eclipse Mars but

```
expression = getExp.next().charAt(0) part gets error always.
```

I didn't understand that what is the error .

Previously i think on this link 
[stackoverflow Scanner question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

am i think wrong ?

Comment: Your while statement does not make any sense as it does not return a boolean.

Comment: You might not understand the error, but you should post the exact error text in full in your question: somebody here will!

Comment: No suggestions available that is ide's error .

Comment: It might not have a suggestion of how to fix the error, but it does have an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want

```
while (getExp.hasNext()) {
    expression = getExp.next().charAt(0);
    ...
}
```