# I cast the scanners int to a char why is this giving me a mismatch exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, type-mismatch

```
public class Practice {
public static void main(String []args){
Scanner ScanMe=new Scanner(System.in);
char ch,answer='K';
System.out.println("I am thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
ch=(char)ScanMe.nextInt();
System.out.println(ch);
if(answer==ch){
System.out.println("CORRECT");
}
}
}
```

I created a new scanner, I created my char variables and then I read my char variables in and its giving a mismatch error???

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Comment: What was your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this to get a char

```
ch = ScanMe.next().charAt(0);
```

also K is not the same as k.

Comment: Dude great answer, I will give u the check when it allows, also why did you put zero in the .charAt, what does that accomplish

Comment: charAt(0) makes sure it only takes the first charter you enter so if you enter abscdsfdfhfgj it only takes the a

Answer (score 2):

Matt's solution is correct, but I wanted to add a bit of clarification. `ch=(char)ScanMe.nextInt();` throws an exception because `ScanMe.nextInt()` gets evaluated first. Assuming you entered a letter, nextInt would throw an exception because a letter is not a decimal integer (which `nextInt` expects).

However, things will work if you enter a decimal integer. For instance, if you enter 75, this method call will work, and when you cast 75 to a char, it's actually 'K', so your program as originally written would say "CORRECT".

Check an ASCII table if that casting doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh I got it, so basically once the nextInt realizes I put anything other then an int in it automatically throws an exception and does not get cast to a char?

Comment: That's pretty much it. As soon as the exception is thrown, no more of the code is executed (until the exception is caught, if ever).

Answer (score 0):

An `Integer` is not a char

Try using `next` and then just using the first char of the String

use `String.charAt(int);`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: but I cast it to an char

Comment: Thats what I said, also you cannot cast from a string to a char, the first letter of a string is not the same as a char value

Comment: use `charAt` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: how do cast 12345 to a char?