# Need help in my java calculator

Tags: java, calculator

i started studying java recently and i tried to program a calculator but it gives me error (and i don't understand why it happens).

PS: Sorry for my bad english

```
package pkg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a number: ");
        int first = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write another number: ");
        int second = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write an operator: ");
        char operator = reader.nextInt();
        if(operator == '+') {
            System.out.println(first + second);
        }
        else if(operator == '-') {
            System.out.println(first - second);
        }
        else if(operator == '*') {
            System.out.println(first * second);
        }
        else if(operator == '/') {
            System.out.println(first / second);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

[image]

Comment: It gives **what** error? This is the most important part of your question, and it's missing.

Comment: Use reader.next().charAt(0) for reading char

Comment: Sorry, i already edited the post

Comment: Check how to get char input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Comment: It's working!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you prompt for an operator, you are trying to read a int, instead of a char. Here's how you should do it:

```
package pkg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a number: ");
        int first = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write another number: ");
        int second = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write an operator: ");
        char operator = reader.next().charAt(0);
        if(operator == '+') {
            System.out.println(first + second);
        }
        else if(operator == '-') {
            System.out.println(first - second);
        }
        else if(operator == '*') {
            System.out.println(first * second);
        }
        else if(operator == '/') {
            System.out.println(first / second);
        }
    }
}
```