# I have to make a simple array program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class testa{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     char m[ ] = new char[10];
     int i,j;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       for(i=0;i<5;i++){
       m[i]=sc.next();//I can do it via bufferedReader but how to o it with Scanner
       }
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    System.out.println(m[j]);
 }
}
```

Now the problem is that i cannot input value and execute it correctly using Scanner class but i can with bufferedreader which i dont want to do.How do i make this program work?   Sample input:qwerty 
Sample output:
q
w
e
r
t
y

Comment: read whole string with `next` and then simply do `m=sc.next().toCharArray()` once

Comment: .charAt(0)but would it accept entire value of qwerty?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Comment: Riddle03 I know the link:) Just look at the question. If i use .charAt(0); it wont give me my desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing :-

```
char c[] = new char[5];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.next();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   c[i] = line.charAt(i);
}
```

This would make a `char` array out of the entered `String`.Well, if you want a `char` array, you could also replace the **loop** with

```
char c[] = line.toCharArray();
```

At the end, just print out the array.

Answer (score 0):

In this line : m[i]=sc.next() it accepts the entire string "qwerty" . You might want to try something like this: 
    `String str= sc.next();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        m[i] =str.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;      // import Scanner class to input array values from user
public class ArrayExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);   //Create an object of Scanner class
    int[] arr=new int[10];      //declare an integer array


    //input value from array
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();        
    }


    //print array values from array
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class testa{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     char[] m = new char[5];
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       m[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
       }
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    System.out.print(m[j] + ' ');
 }
}
```

I believe this should work. I'm on my phone as of writing, so cannot verify.
The important correction being

> .charAt(0) and System.out.print(m[j] + ' ');

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not very efficient, this is the only way I can think of using Scanner.

```
public class testa{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = null;
        do  {
            str = sc.findInLine(pattern);
            if(str!= null)
                System.out.print(str.charAt(0));
                System.out.print(" ");
        } while (str != null);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```