# Java compilation instance

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException {
    char x, y;
    x = 'T';
    System.out.println("*GAME START");
    for(int i=5;i>=0;--i) {
        System.out.println("You Have " + i + " Life");
            y = (char) System.in.read();
            if (y == x)
            {
                System.out.println("**WIN**");
                break;
            }
            else
                {
            if(y>x)
                System.out.println("X<Z");
            else
                System.out.println("X>Z");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in this code?
What compilation problem.

```
*GAME START
You Have 5 Life
A
X>Z
You Have 4 Life
X>Z
You Have 3 Life
```

Why does the code not ask me a new font when print "You Have 4 Life"? 
It prints "You Have 3 Life"  then I can read a new font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to use debugger in such cases.

`System.in.read()` read only one symbol at a time. First is 'A' and second is '\n'. On next loop application will ask you for the next input.

You could look for other implementations [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner) .

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read` reads the next byte of data from the input stream. If you enter any character and press return, the char and the linefeed/carraige return are in the input stream. So skip the Return key.

```
do 
{
    y = (char) System.in.read();
}
while (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(y));
```