# How to add a char into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a question based on character arrays. At the moment I have an `input` variable that takes the first letter of the word.

```
char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

What I want to do is for every enter, I want to put it in an array so that I can keep a log of all the letters that have been retrievied. I am assuming this is using char[] but I am having trouble implementing added each input into the array.

Comment: `scanner.next()` Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner) question that was asked before.

Comment: If you have trouble with code, put down that code here. If you have trouble writing that code: any good book or tutorial tells you how to create arrays, and gives examples how to use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

First thing that's unclear is what Object type is scanner?
But for now I'll assume scanner is the Scanner object from Java.util.Scanner

If that's the case scanner.nextLine() actually returns a String.
String has a charAt() method that will allow you to pick out a character anywhere in the string.

However `scanner.nextLine()` is getting the *entire* line, not just one word. So really `scanner.nextLine().charAt(0)` is getting the first character in the line.

`scanner.next()` will give you the *next* word in the line.
If the line contained "Hello World"
`scanner.next().charAt(0)` would return the character 'H'.
the next call of `scanner.next().charAt(0)` would then return the character 'W'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean finished = false;
    ArrayList<Character> firstLetters = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!finished) {
        firstLetters.add(scanner.next().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

The above code sample might give you the behavior you're looking for.
Please note that the while loop will run forever until `finished` becomes true.
Your program will have to decide when to set `finished` to true.

AND here's a couple of links about Java's Scanner class

- [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm)
- [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)