# Java - read file char by char and count number of lines

Tags: java, chars

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 
public class Doomday
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); //provide file name from outside
    int counter =0; //keep track of how many integers in the file
    while(scan.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        counter++;
        scan.nextInt();
    }
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 
    int a[] = new int[counter];
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        a[i]=scan2.nextInt(); //fill the array with the integers
    }
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }

   }

}
```

The above sample of code reads input from a file, integers, via the command line and stores them into an array. How can I modify the code so as it reads chars from the file? I also want the program to count the lines of the file.

for example, as this for an input

```
+.........-
-+--------.
```

I want to store this into a 2d array . This would be easy if I knew how to count the number of chars and the new lines (since given the number of lines and chars -and each line in my program has the same number of chars- I can find how many rows I have)

So how Can I change the above code to read chars from the file and count the lines of the program?

Can you provide your help with some code?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Check this code. I have made it shorter

To read next line Java has `nextLine()` and to check if there is a next line Java has `hasNextLine()`

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 
public class Dooms
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); //provide file name from outside
    int counter =0; //keep track of how many lines in the file
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = new String(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println(line);
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("There are "+counter+" lines");
    scan.close();

   }

}
```

Now you can easily store the file content in the 2d array with little modification.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I come from a C background and Im extremely new in Java. Is there any function to replace hasNextInt to read chars? Since I want to read the file char by char

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @shubham johar, Java's Scanner class does have nextLine() method that could really simplify the code. Conversion here is to a char array as requested, but those arrays are line by line added into an `ArrayList`, because we cannot in advance know how many lines is going to be there. That is, sort of, the equivalent of a requested 2D array.
If it doesn't matter to be specifically char array, I would recommend usage of `String` class.
For total line count, you can always take the size of an `ArrayList`.
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Doomday {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 
        ArrayList<char []> lines = new ArrayList<char []>();

        while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            lines.add(lineScanner.nextLine().toCharArray());
        }

        for(char line[] : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println("Line count: " + lines.size());

        lineScanner.close();
    }


}
```

**EDIT:**

Version of code, reading file char by char:

```
public class Doomday {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 
        scanner.useDelimiter("");
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);

            if(c == System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0)) {
                numberOfLines++;
                continue;
            }

            // do something with char
        }

        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + numberOfLines);

        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I come from a C background and Im extremely new in Java. Is there any function to replace hasNextInt to read chars?

Comment: Yes, you can use .next() function, but before that, you have to tell your scanner to use empty string as a delimiter. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008444/6945057

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! It really helped!