# Taking char input via Scanner class

Tags: java

I am  trying to insert a char value from scanner class. 
I tried it in the following way.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
character = sc.nextChar();
```

It's not working
Since my next method only take  char value.  I tried it by using sc.charAt(0). it worked. Is there another way to try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
char c= sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Here, you are reading a string and take the first character of it.