# Check input using Java Scanner while typing

Tags: java

I was Trying to find a way to check the user input while typing so if they typed a special character ("#") the execution will terminate immediately without pressing Enter (using Java Scanner) , I tried this code but it needs to press enter each time .I couldn't find a way to do that 
I'd appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);

            while (true) {
                String input =scan.next();
                if (input.equals("#")) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("yes");


            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rd_x, - don't post code in a comment. Update your question with the formatted code so everybody can read the code.

Comment: It may surprise you that this is very hard to do

Answer (score 0):

you may read byte by byte and stop read when entering the special character.

For example:

```
char key;
do{
   key = scanner.nextByte() // be careful with encoding. utf-8 may use 2 bytes per symbol
   //do stuff
}while(key != '#')
```

Comment: I've neve used byte before , but it gave me an error ( Type mismatch : can't covert from byte to char)

Comment: try scanner.nextChar...

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the input char by char. Something like this:

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
if(c == '#')
{
    // terminate execution
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a nextChar() method , is it the same as next() ?

Comment: Yes, It should be next().charAt(0). Remembered it wrong. Code is updated.

Comment: I'm afraid that this reads only the first character

Comment: This might be what you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. System.in.read() will read the entered character. If the entered character is # you can terminate the execution. If the user has entered the enter key you can use the whitespace() method to break out of the loop.

```
char arr[] = new char[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    arr[i] = (char)System.in.read();
    if (arr[i].equals("#")) {
        System.exit(1);
}
if(arr[i].isWhitespace()){
break;
}

}
```

Comment: It gives compiletion errors (can't invoke equlas(Sting) on the primitive type char)& (can't invoke isWhitespace()  on the primitive type char).

Comment: I tried to change .equlas to == and  isWhitespace to =='  ' . It worked but it needs to press enter :(

Comment: Yes System.in.read() method reads the character even if enter is not pressed. Once the user presses enter key it can be detected with whitespace