# Control Flow Condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I fail to understand why For loop keeps executing, if condition meet and break statement applied.

Code:

```
class ProgramControlStatements {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("Choice: ");
        System.out.println("1: If/Else");
        System.out.println("2: Switch");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            chooseOption();
        };
    };

    static void chooseOption() throws java.io.IOException{
        char choice = (char) System.in.read();
        switch(choice){
            case 'a':
                System.out.println("Computer control statement: If/Else");
                break;
            case 'b':
                System.out.println("Computer control statement: Switch");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No valid option");
        };
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

If char **a** chosen, print "If/Else" and expect next input until **i<5**

Computer control statement: If/Else

**Actual result:**

First Input -> a
Computer control statement: If/Else

No valid option

Second input -> b
Computer control statement: Switch

No valid option

Third input -> a
Computer control statement: If/Else

Program ends.

I expect default statement to be skipped since break statement is applied.
Is this happening as System.in.read() returns a new line?
I think same behaviour is to be expected from while; do-while loops?

Answer (score 3):

It's not as easy as @Arvind Kumar Avinash says, depending on your [OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) you may encounter either a `\r` (carriage return), `\n` (new line) or both `\r\n` after every line.

So just adding another `System.in.read()` line is a workaround that may not always work.

I suggest using [Scanner](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-51-java-scanner-nextchar/) instead, as suggested here: [Take a char input from the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner).

LE: As an answer to a request in the comment, I would like to specify that I always try to use `Scanner` when I want to parse my input and don't mind the performance. When I mind performance, I use `BufferedReader`. Never `System.in` directly. You can read more in the answers provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698084/2477456.

Comment: good tip!
I've been trying to understand why should I use System.in.read() vs Scanner.
I was aware of the Scanner Class, and using it whenever input is needed.

Could you point me to a good read on why and when to use System.in.read vs Scanner?

Comment: thank you for the link for end line statements.

Should I raise another question for why/when should I use System Class method .in.read vs Scanner Class?

Comment: If you want a more detailed explaination, I think it's a good idea, as I couldn't find one

Comment: I will do so, thank you.
Will update the link in this chat when I have completed the question.
Hai noroc :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is a combination between the 2 answers offered so far.

For a quick fix, @Arvind Kumar Avinash is very good.

Looking more in to the problem as @Valdrinium specifies alternatives might be considered.

I am sceptical on choosing @Arvind Kumar Avinash as definitive, although it solve the problem in this instance.

Can an admin help?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of the dangling line break character. Just add `System.in.read();` once again as shown below to consume dangling line break character e.g. `(char) System.in.read()` consumes just `a` but not the <kbd>Enter</kbd> character that you press after `a`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("Choice: ");
        System.out.println("1: If/Else");
        System.out.println("2: Switch");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            chooseOption();
        }
    }

    static void chooseOption() throws java.io.IOException {
        char choice = (char) System.in.read();
        System.in.read();// Add this line
        switch (choice) {
        case 'a':
            System.out.println("Computer control statement: If/Else");
            break;
        case 'b':
            System.out.println("Computer control statement: Switch");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No valid option");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Menu: 
Choice: 
1: If/Else
2: Switch
a
Computer control statement: If/Else
b
Computer control statement: Switch
a
Computer control statement: If/Else
b
Computer control statement: Switch
a
Computer control statement: If/Else
```

Comment: thank you. wonderful answer.
Can you point me to read on the dangling line break character.
Not sure I understand that behaviour

Comment: You are most welcome. I've added some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: after Valdrinium answer I am afraid we should define a deeper answer?
Should I raise another question on Scanner vs System Class and address the issue there?