# Java String outputting as blank

Tags: java

I have an assignment where we have to make a Java program that will read 4 inputs from the user:

- Integer
- Double
- Character
- String

Then it outputs them in the above order in one line, and in reverse order in another line.

The inputs are

- Integer: 99
- Double: 3.77
- Character: z
- String: Howdy

However when they are outputted, the String is just blank

Expected results:

```
Enter integer: 
Enter double: 
Enter character: 
Enter string: 
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
3.77 cast to an integer is 3
```

Actual results:

```
Enter integer: 
Enter double: 
Enter character: 
Enter string: 
99 3.77 z 
 z 3.77 99
3.77 cast to an integer is 3
```

Here is the code that I have

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userInt = 0;
      double userDouble = 0.0;
      
      // FIXME Define char and string variables similarly
      char myChar;
      String myString = "";
      
      System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
      userInt = scnr.nextInt();
      
      // FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space
      System.out.println("Enter double: ");
      userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();
      
      System.out.println("Enter character: ");
      myChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      
      System.out.println("Enter string: ");
      myString = scnr.nextLine();
      
      
      System.out.println(userInt + " " + userDouble + " " + myChar + " " + myString);
   
      // FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse
      System.out.println(myString + " " + myChar + " " + userDouble + " " + userInt);
      
      // FIXME (3): Cast the double to an integer, and output that integer
      System.out.println(userDouble + " cast to an integer is " + (int)userDouble);
      
      return;
   }
}
```

How do I get the String to show in the output? It is just displaying as an empty string. I've even tried to initialize the `myString` variable to `"Hello"`, but it still displays empty.

Comment: I would bet it is the same problem as in this question: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) -- that is, `nextLine()` is reading (up to) the newline from previous input (`next()` which does not *consume* the newline from the input) || Solution: add a `dummy* call to `nextLine()` before reading the string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work.

You can request the input on the same line using `System.out.print` and you can use `String.format` to output the variables. Don't forget to close the `Scanner`!

**Note:** When grabbing partial string input, you need to call `scanner.nextLine()` to dump the buffer, before requesting more string values.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Inputs
        int userInt;
        double userDouble;
        char myChar;
        String myString;

        System.out.print("Enter integer: ");
        userInt = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter double: ");
        userDouble = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter character: ");
        myChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        scanner.nextLine(); // Clear the buffer

        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        myString = scanner.nextLine();

        // Output the four values in order
        System.out.printf("%d %.2f %s %s%n", userInt, userDouble, myChar, myString);

        // Output the four values in reverse order
        System.out.printf("%s %s %.2f %d%n", myString, myChar, userDouble, userInt);

        // Cast the double to an integer, and output that integer
        System.out.println(userDouble + " cast to an integer is " + (int) userDouble);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter integer: 99
Enter double: 3.77
Enter character: z
Enter string: Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
3.77 cast to an integer is 3
```

If you want to take all the inputs at once, you can do the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Inputs
        int userInt;
        double userDouble;
        char myChar;
        String myString;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer, double, character, and a string: ");

        userInt = scanner.nextInt();
        userDouble = scanner.nextDouble();
        myChar = scanner.next(".").charAt(0); // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942707/1762224
        myString = scanner.nextLine().trim();

        // Output the four values in order
        System.out.printf("%d %.2f %s %s%n", userInt, userDouble, myChar, myString);

        // Output the four values in reverse order
        System.out.printf("%s %s %.2f %d%n", myString, myChar, userDouble, userInt);

        // Cast the double to an integer, and output that integer
        System.out.println(userDouble + " cast to an integer is " + (int) userDouble);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter an integer, double, character, and a string: 99 3.77 z Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
3.77 cast to an integer is 3
```

If you want to be strict about which charcter can be entered, you can use a pattern:

```java
myChar = scanner.next("[A-Za-z]").charAt(0); // Only alpha
```

Comment: _Don't forget to close the Scanner!_ Not if it wraps `System.in`. In any case it will be closed when the JVM terminates, besides which, in the code in your question, closing the `Scanner` is the last thing that your code does so it's kind of moot, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Basically, it boils down to the scanner can be a bit "finicky" when you use certain commands like "next" instead of "nextline" If I recall when I would use Java I would usually just scan with nextline and then cast after the fact

Comment: Maybe you could post some code demonstrating what you mean and how it relates to the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

we should clear/flush the scanner to remove any residual buffer left in the input buffer.

In you case, you input a character for `myChar` and then you `ENTER` so it will suppose that `myString = scnr.nextLine();` will be an `ENTER` because the `ENTER` be know as the buffer after this input.

```java
myChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);
```

For example: when it's go to input for `myChar`, you type: "c  Howdy" and `ENTER`, so it will know that myChar = 'c' and myString will be "Howdy `ENTER`".

Therefore, we have clear the Scanner to ensure that there are no extra characters/tokens left in the previous input.
In java, when you use Scanner next(), nextInt(), or nextLine() it after leaves the newline character '\n'/

To clear the Scanner buffer, you can use this

```java
Scanner.nextLine();
```

Based on your code, you should use this after input for myChar:

```java
scnr.nextLine();
```

Your full of code should like this

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInt = 0;
        double userDouble = 0.0;
        
        // FIXME Define char and string variables similarly
        char myChar;
        String myString = "";
        
        System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
        userInt = scnr.nextInt();
        
        // FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space
        System.out.println("Enter double: ");
        userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter character: ");
        myChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);
        scnr.nextLine(); // clear buffer
        
        System.out.println("Enter string: ");
        myString = scnr.nextLine();
        
        
        System.out.println(userInt + " " + userDouble + " " + myChar + " " + myString);
        
        // FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse
        System.out.println(myString + " " + myChar + " " + userDouble + " " + userInt);
        
        // FIXME (3): Cast the double to an integer, and output that integer
        System.out.println(userDouble + " cast to an integer is " + (int)userDouble);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... when they are outputted, the String is just blank ..."*

> *"... How do I get the String to show in the output? It is just displaying as an empty string. I've even tried to initialize the `myString` variable to `"Hello"`, but it still displays empty."*

If you're looking to read input one line at a time, use the *[Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* method.
The *next* methods, *nextInt*, *nextDouble*, etc., are used for obtaining values within a single-line.

```java
System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
userInt = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());

// FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space
System.out.println("Enter double: ");
userDouble = Double.parseDouble(scnr.nextLine());

System.out.println("Enter character: ");
myChar = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);

System.out.println("Enter string: ");
myString = scnr.nextLine();
```

Output

```
Enter integer: 
99
Enter double: 
3.77
Enter character: 
z
Enter string: 
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
3.77 cast to an integer is 3
```

Here is an example demonstrating how to read the 4 values when written on one line.
I've added the *[String#stripLeading](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading())* to remove any white-space characters.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
double b = scanner.nextDouble();
char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
String d = scanner.nextLine().stripLeading();
System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s%n%4$s %3$s %2$s %1$s", a, b, c, d);
```

Output

```
99 3.77 z Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative. It only utilizes the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method and makes use of the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method to carry out input validation for each prompt. If a prompt input validation fails, the User is permitted to try again. The User can also quit on any prompt. Be sure to read the comments in code:

```
public class BasicInput {
    
    // OS related newline character sequence:
    public final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    
    // The JVM will automatically close this resource when the application ends.
    private final java.util.Scanner scnr = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    private int userInt;
    private double userDouble;
    private char myChar;
    private String myString = "";
        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need 
           for statics (unless we want them):  */
        new BasicInput().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* List Interface of Object - Will hold the values of the 
           above variables once they are filled.               */
        java.util.List<Object> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.println("Enter 'q' to quit at any time:" + LS);
        
        // PROMPT #1 - Enter Integer Value:
        String intNum = "";
        while (intNum.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer value: -> ");
            intNum = scnr.nextLine().trim(); // Trim off leading/trailing spaces (if any):
            
            // Is quit desired?
            if (intNum.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                quit();
            }
            
            /* VALIDATE USER ENTRY:     
               If the supplied string is NOT (!) a representation of a signed 
               or unsigned integer value which is within Integer.MIN_VALUE
               and Integer.MAX_VALUE then, inform the User and allow him 
               or her to try again:                                   */
            if (!intNum.matches("-?\\d+") || new java.math.BigInteger(intNum).longValue() < Integer.MIN_VALUE 
                                          || new java.math.BigInteger(intNum).longValue() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Integer (int type) Entry! (" + intNum + ") Try again..." + LS);
                intNum = "";
            }
        }
        
        // Fill `userInt` member variable - Convert String to int:
        userInt = Integer.parseInt(intNum);
        // Add to List
        list.add(userInt);  
        
        
        // PROMPT #2 - Enter Floating Point (double type) Value:
        String dblNum = "";
        while (dblNum.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter a floating point value: -> ");
            dblNum = scnr.nextLine().trim(); // Trim off leading/trailing spaces (if any):
            
            // Is quit desired?
            if (dblNum.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                quit();
            }
            
            /* VALIDATE USER ENTRY:     
               If the supplied string is not a representation of a signed 
               or unsigned integer or floating point value then, inform
               the User and allow him/her to try again:              */
            if (!dblNum.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Floating-Point Entry! (" 
                                   + dblNum + ") Try again..." + LS);
                dblNum = "";
            }
        }

        // Fill `userDouble` member variable - Convert String to double:
        userDouble = Double.parseDouble(dblNum);
        // Add to List:
        list.add(userDouble);
        
        
        // PROMPT #3 - Enter A Specific Character:
        String charVal = "";
        while (charVal.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter a specific character (one only and no spaces): -> ");
            charVal = scnr.nextLine().trim(); // Trim off leading/trailing spaces (if any):
            
            // Is quit desired?
            if (charVal.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                quit();
            }
            
            /* VALIDATION - If nothing or just one or more white-spaces (tabs, etc) 
               are supplied then re-loop:           */
            if (charVal.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Entry! You must supply a keyboard character!" + LS);
            }
        }
        
        // Fill `myChar` member variable - Get first character (only) from User's entry:
        myChar = charVal.charAt(0);
        // Add to List:
        list.add(myChar);
        

        // PROMPT #4 - Enter A Specific String:
        String strgVal = "";
        while (strgVal.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter any specific string (not just spaces): -> ");
            strgVal = scnr.nextLine().trim();
            
            // Is quit desired?
            if (strgVal.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                quit();
            }
            
            /* VALIDATION - If nothing or just one or more white-spaces (tabs, etc) 
               are supplied then re-loop:           */
            if (strgVal.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Entry! Your string must contain something!" + LS);
            }
        }

        // Fill `myString` member variable:
        myString = strgVal;
        // Add to List:
        list.add(myString);

        
        // Display Listed Values, Forward:
        System.out.println(LS + "Forward:  " + list.stream().map(Object::toString)
                           .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" ")));

        // Display Listed values, Reversed
        java.util.Collections.reverse(list); // Reverse the elements in List
        System.out.println("Reverse:  " + list.stream().map(Object::toString)
                           .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" ")));

        
        // Cast the double to an integer, and output that integer
        System.out.println("Double " + userDouble + " cast to an integer is: " + (int) userDouble);
    }

    private void quit() {
        System.out.println(LS + "Quiting - Bye Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```