# Non Greedy Regex Start With But Doesn't Contain String

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to extract certain URLs from HTML (for example, all that begin with http, contain /tempfiles/ and end in .jpg). I have something like;

`http.*?\/tempfiles\/.*?\.jpg`

The problem is when I have HTML like;

```
blah blah <img src=http://somelink/file.html>http://server/tempfiles/blah.jpg
blah blah
```

It returns `http://somelink/file.html etc
    more junk http://server/tempfiles/blah.jpg`

Is there a way to say there must not be a second http between the first and the /tempfiles/?

Comment: forbid whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181271/regex-to-match-a-single-character-that-is-anything-but-a-space

Comment: Try `http:\/\/[^\/]+\/tempfiles\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*\w+\.\jpg` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIxqYc/2)

Comment: @trollingchar I have tweaked the question a little to show this won't always work. I have found a workaround (I'm actually forbidding quotes) but still want to know the answer as i'm sure there must be something to say "match anything except this"?

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you elaborate a tad on what/how yours works? (I haven't tested it, but I can't see anywhere it looks like you're saying don't match http?

Comment: @LeeTickett I have updated my comment. Can you try matching the format of the url `http://[^/]+\/tempfiles/(?:[^/]+\/)*\w+\.jpg` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxGv7R/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I follow that one slightly better, but still not flexible enough (it broken when i tried changing it to `<img src=http://somelink/file.html>http://server/diff-folder/tempfiles/blah.jpg`

Comment: Then you could use `http://[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*/tempfiles/(?:[^/]+\/)*\w+\.jpg` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxGv7R/2)

Comment: Or simply `http://[^:]+/tempfiles/(?:[^/]+\/)*\w+\.jpg` perhaps?

Comment: Your next problem will be with something like `http://server/tempfiles/blah.txt>http://server/image/blah.jpg`  You're so much better off if you just parse the html with a proper parser and then doing regex on the text you extract.

Comment: @juharr exactly why I was looking for the "not containing http" command... which `Wiktor Stribiżew` has provided in his answer below.

Comment: @LeeTickett That will match the whole thing I just put in because there isn't an `http` between the first `http` and the `/tempfiles/`.  Then if you make sure there isn't a `http` between the `/tempfiles/` and the `jpg` that would still match this `http://server/tempfiles/blah.txt>blah.jpg`.  What you really need is to delimit where things end with whitespace and `>` and `<` which would quickly become a regex that snowballs out of control.

Comment: @juharr good spot- but I have what I need now to extrapolate so to speak :) `http(?:(?!http).)*?/tempfiles/(?:(?!http).)*?\.jpg` I think would do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
http(?:(?!http).)*?/tempfiles/.*?\.jpg
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kaOcbE/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=http(%3F%3A(%3F!http).)*%3F%2Ftempfiles%2F.*%3F%5C.jpg):

[image]

**Details**

- `http` - a `http` substring
- `(?:(?!http).)*?`  - any char other than a newline char, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start a `http` char sequence
- `/tempfiles/` - a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `\.jpg` - a `.jpg` substring.

Comment: Legend. Easy when you know how!? I removed the ?: to end up with `http((?!http).)*?/tempfiles/.*?\.jpg` any reason why you had them in there?

Comment: @LeeTickett Do not use a capturing group here, it will hamper matching. Use a non-capturing group. Or, compile the regex with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` option. All capturing groups will behaves as non-capturing then. Actually, you may just prepend the pattern with `(?n)` then.

Comment: Just did a quick search. Does using non capturing groups just optimise/speed things up?

Comment: @LeeTickett Yes, and in this case of a tempered greedy token, to a greater extent.